# Error in phicoef() in r

Tags: r, coefficients

If I do :

```
m <- matrix(c(3,1914,689993,346109647),nrow=2,ncol=2)
phicoef(m)
```

it gives me:

```
Error in phicoef(m) : 
when 'y' is not supplied, 'x' must be a 2x2 integer matrix or an integer vector of length 4.
```

what shoul I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an integer matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(3L,1914L,689993L,346109647L),nrow=2,ncol=2)
typeof(m)
#[1] "integer"
```